# Using keyup to change absolute position using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

All I'm trying to do is to simply move a div around the screen using my arrow keys. I am completely newbie to JavaScript and what I wrote seems like it should be working but it's not. Every keyUp is moving the div based on it's original position and not the current position of the div. Is there something I'm missing?

CSS: 
    #pawn {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

JavaScript

```
 function showKeyCode(e) {

    var pawn = document.getElementById("pawn");

    if(e.keyCode == "37") {
        console.log("left");
        pawn.style.left = -50+"px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == "38") {
        console.log("up");
        pawn.style.top = -50+"px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == "39") {
        console.log("right");
        pawn.style.left = +50+"px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == "40") {
        console.log("down");
        pawn.style.top = +50+"px";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body onKeyUp="showKeyCode(event);">
  <div id="pawn"></div>
 </body>
```

Can anyone shine some light on this? I've been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pawn.style.left` properties are text, so you're not actually incrementing the value at all. Essentially the assignments say "set it to positive/negative `50+"px";` every time.

You'll need to convert the values to integers and then add the new value, and then set it as the `px` value.

A very basic demo in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('keyup', function(e){
    var pawn = $('#pawn');
    var newLeft = parseInt(pawn.css('left')) + 50;
    pawn.css('left',newLeft+'px');
  });
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/wILGc)

You can infer how to add support for the different directions/arrow keys.

Comment: I did what you said and ask you can see here, it no longer moves? http://jsfiddle.net/yG6fa/

Comment: You needed checks for the initial default (empty) style values, i.e. `if( pawn.style.left === '' ) pawn.style.left = 0;` - it works now - http://jsfiddle.net/yG6fa/2/

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing that but did it incorrectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the position value but also take in count that the value you save is a string so you need to convert that back to a number so you can increment it again.

```js
var pawn = document.getElementById("pawn");
var move = 50;

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', showKeyCode);

function showKeyCode(e) {
  var num = 0;
  if(e.keyCode === 37) {
    num = parseInt(pawn.style.left, 10) || 0;
    num -= move;
    pawn.style.left = num + "px";
  }
  if(e.keyCode === 38) {    
    num = parseInt(pawn.style.top, 10) || 0;
    num -= move;
    pawn.style.top = num + "px";
  }

  if(e.keyCode === 39) {
    num = parseInt(pawn.style.left, 10) || 0;
    num += move;
    pawn.style.left = num + "px";
  }

  if(e.keyCode === 40) {
    num = parseInt(pawn.style.top, 10) || 0;
    num += move;
    pawn.style.top = num + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
}


#pawn {
  background-color: #B0BEC5;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pawn">pawn</div>
```